# Subclassing ViewController Swift

Tags: swift2, subclassing

Sorry if the question has been ask before.. I have looked without finding it.

I am building an IOS application with Swift2. I have a very long main class (ViewController: UIViewController).

I am trying to reorganise my code by subclassing view controller in another two new classes Customer:Viewcontroller and Server:ViewController.

My goal is that those two classed get executed adding extended functionality to me viewcontroller, and extension is not useful to me because I am overriding on the subclasses.

How can I do to execute these classes when app lauched.

Now my code is organised like this...

```
//ViewController handling now almost all my code
class ViewController: UIViewController,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,MPCManagerDelegate,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UINavigationControllerDelegate {

///some variables 

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
////some other stuff
}
///some other functions
}



///Server subclass My goal is to print ("subclassing after view controller 's didload function

class server:ViewController {



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print ("loaded extern class")
}
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. What's the desired outcome, and what in fact is happening or not happening? [Also, is that your real code? If so, change it. Don't start the name of a class, `server`, with a small letter.]

Comment: sorry last comment was a tipping error.. Not my real code...Write now I only have the viewcontroller class and a few more. 
I access the other classe's methods by putting something=otherclasses(); something.othermethods().

What I want now is...

ViewController have around 2000 lines. I want to split it up on subclasses (or something) for better control over my code.

Write now... only for simplicity I only want to print out "laded external class" once my main class viewDidLoad is executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subclass the other classes in Swift like the following:

```
var subclassedServer = server()
```

And to access any variable inside it just do like :

```
subclassedServer.somethingelse = value
```

Good luck !

Comment: My goal is to execute it as I do it on android... Run the subclass and on the subclass call the superclass method as super.method... on override...
My final goal is to run the subclass first and call the super class method with super.method to be able to override these methods

Comment: Just so you know not everything in android can be converted to iOS ! Are you connecting the classes for a views or you just want to excite code ? What are you trying to do exactly ?? Give me a clear example and I'll help you !

Comment: I am trying to organize my code on separate files. I have a really long class I am looking a way of split it off with the same functionallity. 
I was thinking in subclassing but I accept other solutions.

Comment: actually it was solved using extensions and custom classes with delegate methods. Thanks all for viewing this